# Route traffic to specific network through specific interface

Tags: ubuntu, ip, routing, route

I have a Ubuntu server *hosted on Digital Ocean* and used as a VPN and through it I would like to access my other servers there over the local network (*Private Network*). But I am unable to access other servers from my PC over the VPN (*Request timed out on 10.8.0.1 = VPN server*). 
Route table on the VPN server:

```
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens3
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
10.19.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 ens3
10.19.0.0       10.19.0.1       255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 ens3
10.135.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 ens4
10.135.0.0      10.135.0.1      255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 ens4
7.7.7.0         0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 ens3
```

tun0 is VPN network 
ens3 is to the internet 
ens4 is LAN 
*/Public net masked as 7.7.7.0/*

So I would like to route all traffic going from 10.8.0.0/24 to 10.135.0.0/16 over ens4 (10.135.4.48) and all other traffic through ens3.

Do I have to change routing on my local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by amending ufw config at /etc/ufw/before.rules:

```
# nat Table rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

# Forward traffic from eth1 through eth0.
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -d 10.135.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE

COMMIT
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer so the question gets closed. Thanks.